# Why isn't my site displaying the side navigation?

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout

It's really bugging me and I have no idea why when I view this site on my mobile, it only shows the middle section and not the sides. 
My side navigation is on the left side and completely cuts it out and I can't scroll to it.

Is there some sort of media query I could try? or change my CSS somehow?

Sorry I'f I'm being vague but I have no idea what to ask to make it work.

Here's the site www.joetest.comyr.com

thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Please include enough information in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically when the site is viewed on mobile, you can only see what's inside the wrapper which has a defined width of 1220px I believe.
The side nav bar is inside the wrapper but I have offset it to the side with margin-top and margin-left.
my browser does the same thing when I reduce it down.
I just don't understand why the browser/mobile doesn't display 100% of the page. I hope that helps

Comment: "Enough information" would include enough of the HTML and CSS of your site to demonstrate the problem (but not too much!)

Comment: ok I've inputted my code to http://jsfiddle.net/qTXLc/

If you look at the result you can see my navigation box coming in from the left, but you can't see it completely.
I want to know why the screen isn't allowing it onto the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the width of the #mainpage set rather than a max-width, so as the page is scaled down, the #mainpage is taking the whole screen. Also, you have a negative margin-left set on the #leftpanel which pulls it off the screen when the screen size is smaller. I was messing around with your site using firebug right now and by removing the margin-left attribute I was able to keep the menu on the page while resizing the browser.

You're probably going to have to change your html structure though if you want to retain the exact layout on smaller screens.

Comment: But by removing the negative margin from #leftpanel, it will sit on inside the main page where it's blocking other content

Comment: Which is why I suggested you change the html structure. By putting the left menu inside of a container div you wont need to use a negative margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/75E5W/